# Can't get most recent post from categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a category and loop through its sub categories getting one post from each of those sub-categories. Below is my code:

```
<? 
$homepage_cat = get_category_by_slug( 'home-page-slider' );

$id = $homepage_cat->cat_ID;

print($id);

$sub_cat = get_categories('hide_empty=0&child_of=' . $id);

print_r($sub_cat);

    foreach ($sub_cat as $key => $cat) 
    {
        echo $cat->term_id;
        query_posts('cat=' . $cat->term_id);
        if ( have_posts() ) 
        {  echo '<h1> HELL YEAH </h1>';
            while ( have_posts() ) 
            { 
              echo  '<h1>' get_the_title(); '</h1>'; 
            } // end while
        }  // end if
    } //end foreach
?>
```

The code is not returing any posts as `HELL YEAH` is not being echoed. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Try change `showposts` with `posts_per_page`, you might need to use the `setup_postdata` function, too.

Comment: Thanks Tomas how would I use the setup_postdata function? I don't think this is the issue as I'm getting the desired number of categories which is 3. However when I loop through those three to get the latest post it returns 3 empty arrays, one for each category.

Comment: Where do you set this var `$homepage_cat`?

Comment: that is set above. It definitely works. This is on index.php though. There is a post loop on the same page. Will that affect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few problems here

- First of all, never use `query_posts` to construct custom queries. It breaks the main query, is unreliable and outright fails in most cases in pagination
- Secondly, you have to reset your postdata after every custom query
- Thirdly, never use short tags. Always use full tag ie `<?php` and not just `<?`
- Lastly, you are missing `the_post()` which should return post objects

Your query should look something like this

```
<?php 
$homepage_cat = get_category_by_slug( 'home-page-slider' );

$id = $homepage_cat->cat_ID;

print($id);

$sub_cat = get_categories('posts_per_page=1&hide_empty=0&child_of=' . $id);

print_r($sub_cat);

    foreach ($sub_cat as $key => $cat) 
    {
        echo $cat->cat_ID;
        $q = new WP_Query('cat=' . $cat->cat_ID);
        if ( $q->have_posts() ) 
        {  echo '<h1> HELL YEAH </h1>';
            while ( $q->have_posts() ) 
            { 
                 $q->the_post();
                 echo  '<h1>' get_the_title(); '</h1>'; 
            } // end while
        }  // end if
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } //end foreach
?>
```

Comment: Any progress so far on your problem :-)

Comment: Yeah it was a foolish error on my behalf. I was querying a custom post type. The site only contains custom post types and I though that they would fall into the general category of posts and would be returned. This assumption was incorrect. Thus once I defined the post type it worked as desired. Thank-you your answer was very helpful in regards to query structure and allowed me to eliminate possible options.

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_posts()` not `query_posts`, it is better for these kinds of situations.

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category' => $cat->term_id);
$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
   <h1><?php get_the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this

```
$post_args = array(
   'showposts' => 1,
   'cat' => $cat->term_id 
);
```

with this.

```
$post_args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'category' => $cat->term_id 
);
```

I hope it'll work.

Comment: No joy with that one.